# Lazy associations in TypeORM

Tags: typeorm

In [official docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/next/docs/eager-and-lazy-relations.md), I see this example:

```
const question = await connection.getRepository(Question).findOne(1);
const categories = await question.categories;
```

Based on the above example I had assumed that when I do findOne/find from a repository, the object(s) I get back will have getters defined (for lazy relations) which I can use to further fetch these relations.

However given a model like:

```
@Entity()
export class Issue {
    @ManyToOne(
        type => User,
        user => user.createdIssues,
        {
            onDelete: "CASCADE"
        }
    )
    @Index()
    creator: Promise<User>;

}
```

When I do something like `getRepository(Issue).findOne({})` The resolved object has no creator member.

What am I missing here ?